# pipenv OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system

Tags: python, virtualenv, pipenv

I'm trying to install a package with pipenv install but I keep getting this error message:

```
OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/lib'
```

installing the same packages with pip install works fine

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: `cat ~/.pydistutils.cfg`

Comment: https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/issues/209

Answer (score 1):

Usually an empty prefix in setup.cfg or pydistutils.cfg is the problem. Delete the file entirely or the prefix line

```
[install]
prefix=
```